# jQuery being loaded into gtm.js from Google Tag Manager

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've been having an issue where jQuery v1.9.1 is being included into the top of the gtm.js file.  It causes a few issues and can blow away jQuery plugins that are already loaded on jQuery.fn.  Regression testing is also a concern.  I checked and I don't appear to have any custom tags in the Google Tag Manager that loads jQuery.

Ultimately I want to have control over the host domain and version of jQuery loaded.  Is there a configuration setting in the GTM interface or some other way that I can disable the inclusion of jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that the jQuery code that is included in gtm.js is customized and not globally available.

I did a quick test, and neither `jQuery` nor `$` are defined when I just insert the GTM snippet into a page.

(`window.$` actually *is* defined, but that's a Chrome thing: [Commandline API Reference](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#selector))

Comment: This is good to hear.  I no longer have the problem of JQuery being included in the gtm.js file.  Our marketing department had a third party vendor who did a lot of shady custom HTML and custom JavaScript tags in GTM. Over half of it has caused live site issues. Most if not all of their code has been removed at this point.  It's possible they may have hid it in a macro somewhere.  Your answer serves to confirm my suspicions.