# How do I change the version of jQuery that GTM code includes?

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have an issue whereby the GTM code I have inserted into the website I'm developing in Wordpress has brought in v1.9.1 of a jQuery library that conflicts with the already externally declared v1.11.3 of jQuery.

It's causing this error to appear in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
```

I'm pretty sure that the issue is a conflict in the jQuery script libraries. Obviously the error is saying that the JS should note be declaring jQuery using the shorthand method. I have done the usual and checked to see if plugins were conflicting, but it's definitely the GTM script.

the jQuery v1.11.3 library is declared in the `<head>` and the GTM code is placed directly after the `<body>` tag.

I've done some researching and found these posts to back up my investigations:

[Jquery and Google Tag Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755168/jquery-and-google-tag-manager)

[jQuery being loaded into gtm.js from Google Tag Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207431/jquery-being-loaded-into-gtm-js-from-google-tag-manager)

Both posts talk about changing the included jQuery library. How do I do that? I have been supplied the GTM code by a 3rd party and do not have access to their GA account.

Also, does GTM have to be dependant on jQuery. Is there like a 'Vanilla' version available?

Answer (score 1):

According to the copyright notices the GTM boilerplate code has indeed a version of jQuery 1.9.1 embedded. However this is a customized version that runs inside a private(-ish) function and does not declare a global "$" oder "jQuery" variable.

(short **Update** I attended a seminar by Simo Ahava (who is a Google Developer Expert for GTM) and he said that GTM does not include jQuery, but that some methods GTM uses in its selector engine resemble so closely the jQuery methods that it was deemed necessary to include a copyright notice).

Are  there any marketing tags in the GTM container ? If so I suggest using Ghostery to switch them off one by one to see if the error disappears (some vendors are inconsiderate enough to include scripting libraries within their marketing tags).

Note that in your linked question "jQuery and Google Tag Manager" the jQuery CDN was referenced from within GTM - in that case it was not the built-in version of jQuery that interfered.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not familiar with using Ghostery. Is it this site http://ghostery.com/ ?

Comment: Yes. Ghostery is an ad blocking tool (note  that their business model is to collect data on what is blocked via their plugin) that allows you to selectively disable marketing and analytics tags in your browser.

Comment: Ghostery is not doing much for me that I can't figure out for myself unfortunately. Nice tool though. I did not pick up any extra 'marketing tags' - but then again I'm not too entirely sure what I am looking for. I get the feeling it's a WP theme issue.